# NullPointerException when setting OnClickListener

Tags: android, android-layout, button, nullpointerexception

For some unknown reason I'm getting FATAL EXCEPTION: main - java.lang.NullPointerException on the line:

```
x_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
```

but I'm not sure why this is happening. The button is there - so I'm not sure why a null pointer would occur at this point - but it is.

Any input is greatly appreciated.

SOURCE SNIPPET:

```
@Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            super.onPostExecute(result);
            // Show updated screen if table was successfully updated
            // Or alert indicating settings are not updated
            if (result.equals("success")) {

                setContentView(R.layout.completion);

            } else
                setContentView(R.layout.error);

            Button x_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.x_button);
            x_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    finishAll(v);
                }
            });
        }
```

LOGCAT:

```
08-26 15:49:42.419: W/System.err(5998): java.io.IOException: Stream is closed
08-26 15:49:42.429: W/System.err(5998):     at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.read(GZIPInputStream.java:161)
08-26 15:49:42.429: W/System.err(5998):     at java.io.DataInputStream.read(DataInputStream.java:95)
08-26 15:49:42.429: W/System.err(5998):     at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:255)
08-26 15:49:42.429: W/System.err(5998):     at java.io.BufferedReader.fillBuf(BufferedReader.java:128)
08-26 15:49:42.429: W/System.err(5998):     at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:357)
08-26 15:49:42.429: W/System.err(5998):     at com.tracfone.straighttalk.networktasklibrary.NetworkTask.doInBackground(NetworkTask.java:37)
08-26 15:49:42.429: W/System.err(5998):     at com.tracfone.straighttalk.networktasklibrary.NetworkTask.doInBackground(NetworkTask.java:1)
08-26 15:49:42.429: W/System.err(5998):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
08-26 15:49:42.429: W/System.err(5998):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
08-26 15:49:42.429: W/System.err(5998):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
08-26 15:49:42.429: W/System.err(5998):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
08-26 15:49:42.429: W/System.err(5998):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
08-26 15:49:42.429: W/System.err(5998):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
08-26 15:49:46.299: W/dalvikvm(5998): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4016e560)
08-26 15:49:46.299: E/AndroidRuntime(5998): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-26 15:49:46.299: E/AndroidRuntime(5998): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-26 15:49:46.299: E/AndroidRuntime(5998):     at com.project.new.datasettings.ConfigFinalActivity$TableUpdateRequestTask.onPostExecute(ConfigFinalActivity.java:552)
08-26 15:49:46.299: E/AndroidRuntime(5998):     at com.project.new.datasettings.ConfigFinalActivity$TableUpdateRequestTask.onPostExecute(ConfigFinalActivity.java:1)
08-26 15:49:46.299: E/AndroidRuntime(5998):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:417)
08-26 15:49:46.299: E/AndroidRuntime(5998):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$300(AsyncTask.java:127)
08-26 15:49:46.299: E/AndroidRuntime(5998):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:429)
08-26 15:49:46.299: E/AndroidRuntime(5998):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-26 15:49:46.299: E/AndroidRuntime(5998):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
08-26 15:49:46.299: E/AndroidRuntime(5998):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3821)
08-26 15:49:46.299: E/AndroidRuntime(5998):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-26 15:49:46.299: E/AndroidRuntime(5998):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
08-26 15:49:46.299: E/AndroidRuntime(5998):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:875)
08-26 15:49:46.299: E/AndroidRuntime(5998):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:633)
08-26 15:49:46.299: E/AndroidRuntime(5998):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

FULL SOURCE:

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1ap5qknNcn9RaJhewc9CarQja2uS4Xjgtzw4eNzXzLKY/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: does `x_button` exist both on `R.layout.completion` and `R.layout.error`? If not which one is getting used? Also add a null check on `x_button` before you call setOnClickListener(). From what you've posted here the most likely thing is that x_button is null, which could be caused if it is not present in the layout that is showing at the time you call `findViewById` make a log statment to check to see if it is null after findViewById()

Comment: What class is this part of?  What android base class is it derived from?

Comment: @FoamyGuy put that out as the answer and I'll click it up.

Comment: x_button only exists in R.layout.completion - the issue began occuring when I attempted to implement NetworkTask as a library - which I believe may be causing the issue since it does not have any graphic resources - but I'm not sure (I added a link to show my full source code above - I think it may be helpful)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Your NullpointerException occurs because the Button "x_button" is null, which means that findViewById(...) could not find a Button with the id you provided.**

I see 2 possible reasons for that:

- The **"R.id.x_button" is in neither of your two layout files** "completion" and "error" but in some other layout file instead. This will cause no compiler error to come up, but will cause the Nullpointer upon running the code.
- the **"R.id.x_button" is just in one of them, but you are using the other one** in setContentView(...), depending on your "success".

What I would **recommend**:

> Check your layout files "error" and "completion" and see if the both
>   contain a Button with the id "R.id.x_button", if not, change your code
>   or add the Button to the layout file.

If your Button for example only exists in "completion", you need to change your code to this:

```
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        super.onPostExecute(result);
        // Show updated screen if table was successfully updated
        // Or alert indicating settings are not updated
        if (result.equals("success")) {

            setContentView(R.layout.completion);

            Button x_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.x_button);
            x_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    finishAll(v);
                }
             });
        } else
            setContentView(R.layout.error);
    }
```

This will avoid the NullPointer, because the Button is only initialized when the layout that actually contains the Button is loaded.

Comment: x_button only exists in R.layout.completion - the issue began occuring when I attempted to implement NetworkTask as a library - which I believe may be causing the issue since it does not have any graphic resources - but I'm not sure (I added a link to show my full source code above - I think it may be helpful)